# How to access a local object in a dictionary with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have nested object

```
var model = {
    weather: {
        allData: ""
    },

    woeid: {
        id: 2389646,
        searchText: "davis",
        woeidScript: "some string'"+searchText+"' another string",
        forcastScript: "",
        found: true
    }

};
```

`searchText` in `woeidScript` returns undefined. How can reference this local object?

Comment: You cannot access parts of an object in the middle of its object initializer block. You have to use a separate statement.

Comment: `searchText` references the variable called that. In order to DRY, we would have to look at the code surrounding it.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

An advantage is, you can assign other values to property `valueA` or `valueB` and get the actual result of the division.

-- And a direct reference to the object.

```js
var model = {
    weather: {
        allData: ""
    },
    woeid: {
        id: 2389646,
        searchText: "davis",
        get woeidScript() { return "some string'" + model.woeid.searchText + "' another string"; },
        forcastScript: "",
        found: true
    }
};
document.write(model.woeid.woeidScript);
```